# Virtualbox and Bonding

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, lubuntu, bonding

I'm using Virtualbox on a Lubuntu Host machine. The host machine now has two NICs called `enp0s31f6` and `enp4s0` that are joined in a bond interface called `bond0`.
The bond uses bond mode 802.3ad, network from and to the server works correctly.

Now I'm trying to configure my virtual machines. I have 3 VMs, all using a bridged network which worked fine before creating the bond interface on the host.

I assumed, I can just select the bond0 network adapter for the virtual machines so they can make use of the bonded connection, but I was wrong. Outbound connections from the VM work correctly, but inbound connections do not.

If I select one of the NICs directly (let's say `enp4s0`), it only works for half of the machines trying to reach the VM. I assume because of bond mode 802.3ad, half the connections use `enp0s31f6`, the other half use `enp4s0`. Depending on which machine is trying to access the VM, it might use the correct NIC or it's trying to use the other NIC.

I saw solutions using NAT and port forwarding, but I would really like to keep the VMs bridged if at all possible.

Is there a way to have a bond interface on the host and have it work in a virtual machine ?
Do I need to connect both physical cards to the VM and create another bonding interface inside the VM or something like that?

Comment: I have a very similar configuration (but I use containers, lxc's, instead of VMs), which works flawlessly. Which kind of VMs do you use, and what  exactly is the *input* problem you face when you bridge the bonded interface?

Comment: Besides the VMs, I have docker containers running which also work flawlessly. One example is a VM with a Ubuntu Guest OS that runs Influx and Grafana. When using bond0 with the above config, only half the machines can ping the VM or access the Grafana UI. The others simply time out. This one could be moved to docker too of course. But another VM I have can not be run in Docker though.

Comment: Thank you, I meant which hypervisor are you using?

Comment: Sorry, don't fully understand. I'm using VIrtualbox. Do you mean something else?

Comment: There are alternatives to VirtualBox. Try changing the network adapter, in particular try para-virtio, and then at least some of the others (VirtualBox has 8, only 4 accessible from the GUI).

Comment: None of the alternatives worked either. So finally, I ended up migrating Influx / Grafana to Docker too and so got rid of the last VM I had running.